# Database connection (Cannot open database "VRM" requested by the login.)

Tags: .net, sql-server, networking

I'm getting Error when running my website on host. Unable to open database connection for the following application(s) .... Received exception. Message: Cannot open database "VRM" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool'.

```
Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open database "VRM" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool'.

Source Error:


Line 33:             {
Line 34: 
Line 35:                 throw;
Line 36: 
Line 37:             }


Source File: D:\Final Code\VRM\VRM\Manager\LoginManager.cs    Line: 35

Stack Trace:


[SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database "VRM" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool'.]
```

Comment: Could you please add code where you are trying to access the database, Put more to help others help you

Comment: That error means that either there is no database named VRM or that the user [IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool] doesn't have access to that database.

Comment: Can you try to change the User in the Application Pool to a user can Login to the VRM Database?

Comment: @VolkmarRigo i have no idea about Application Pool, where is it?

Comment: @MustafaSaeed this is my web.config.xml   [link](https://gist.github.com/imranamanat/4f80724d8e12c64a2aa87cf264091779)

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft please help me out from this

Comment: @helloworld what are you using to host your web application? IIS? Maybe this [tutorial](https://thycotic.force.com/support/s/article/Best-Adv-Install-Using-a-Service-Account-to-Run-IIS-App-Pool-and-SQL-DB) helps.

Comment: @VolkmarRigo i was follow this tutorial but in the end "Granting Folder Permissions" i don't no about this :( can you please help me on skype.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your connection strings, either change them both to Username/password auth, or grant that account access to the target database.  You can provision access with a script like the following, which will grant the app pool identity full control on the target database:

```
use vrm

create login [IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool] from windows
create user [IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool] for login [IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool]
grant control to [IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool]
```

You can run the script after connecting to SQL Server using [SQL Server Management Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms) or the sqlcmd.exe command line tool.

For a production application, you would want to limit the permissions granted to the application identity.  This will help protect against SQL Injection vulnerabilities.  EG

```
use vrm

create login [IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool] from windows
create user [IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool] for login [IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool]
create role AppUser
grant select, execute, insert, update, delete on schema::dbo to AppUser
alter role AppUser add member [IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool]
```